# objects disappearing while app is running

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am developing an app for Windows Phone 8 in C#

I have 16 `TextBox` in the **MainPage Layout** .

The `Visibility` value of all the TextBoxes is : `Visible`

The `Opacity` value of all the TextBoxes is : `100%`

When the App **starts running** , all the 16 TextBoxes are showen and everything is working well.

The problem is when i click on a specefic button which it executes a number of processes , some of them contains playing `StoryBoard`'s ( `Animations` )

all the 16 TextBoxes disappeares , i Debugged the app , and checked the value of the `Visibility` and `Opacity` properties **AFTER** the click , and they didn't change !

and also , all the processes that was executed after the click they don't affect any of the TextBoxes , i checked all the references of each one , they were never used in any line of code.

I have a reset button too which assign an empty string ( `tb1.Text = "";` )
 for all the `TextBox`es
when i click on it **AFTER** they disappear , it showes them
and this is weird too , because the code does not affect Visibility or Opacity properties too

Reset button code :

```
private void reset_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        t1.Text = "";
        t2.Text = "";
        t3.Text = "";
        t4.Text = "";
        t5.Text = "";
        t6.Text = "";
        t7.Text = "";
        t8.Text = "";
        g1.Text = "";
        g2.Text = "";
        g3.Text = "";
        g4.Text = "";
        g5.Text = "";
        g6.Text = "";
        g7.Text = "";
        g8.Text = "";
  }
```

**UPDATE:**
After tracing every line of code , i found out that , the process that makes this bug is  `fadeImage.Begin();` which is a `Storyboard` and it what it does is making an animation of a picture fading in , i replaced the line of playing the animation of `fadeImage` with another animation  , and the `TextBox`es doesn't disappear , so the problem isn't with `Storyboard` in general , but with `fadeImage` specifically

XAML CODE :

```
    <Storyboard x:Name="fadeImage" Completed="fadeImage_Completed">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="1"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
```

C# :

```
fadeImage.SetValue(Storyboard.TargetNameProperty, CroppedImage.Name);
fadeImage.Begin();
```

Could it be a Windows Phone 8 bug ?

Comment: How do you estimate the chances of a Windows Phone bug compared to a bug in your code? Are you *that* good? Maybe posting your own code will help a lot more than random guesses.

Comment: @nvoigt because there are ALOT of Windows Phone developing bugs , and it looks reasonable to say such thing , because i tried every method of finding any bugs in my code , but i am not able to , and if posting a very long code that doesn't contain any reference of any of the `TextBox`es will help , i will do it

Comment: What do you expect to gain here? Are you looking for a "yes"? Because without your code, nobody will be able to help you. Do what developers do: *debug*. Shorten your code until the behaviour is ok. what you took out last will likely be the cause. If you can produce a small, self contained sample with the bug, *then* you can think about a bug in other peoples code.

Comment: You seem to have a Refresh related problem, probably in how the animation(s) end. Without any code there can be no answer.